# How to capture the form value as object in angular6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a form contains some text boxes, select and checkbox,while submit the form I need to capture the value of all input fields in the format of {"email":"test@mail.com","password":"test123","list":["one"],"groups":["group1","group2"]} and to show in a console.I have used the formsmodule of angular. Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="getFormData()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">List:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="list">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Group:</label>
   <input type="checkbox"  name="check1" value="group1">group1
   <input type="checkbox"  name="check2" value="group2">group2
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;

  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {


  }
   getFormData(){
      alert('hi');
  }


}
```

Comment: I think you'd be better served by looking into an Angular forms intro tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using either ngModel or Formgroup.
I prefer Formgroup for small forms.

In your **app.module.ts** add the Reactive forms module

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ]
})
```

In your **app.component.html**

```
    <form [formGroup]="dataGroup">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">List:</label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="list" id="list" multiple>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Group:</label>
   <input type="checkbox" (change)="onCheckChange($event)" name="check1" value="group1">group1
   <input type="checkbox" (change)="onCheckChange($event)"  name="check2" value="group2">group2
  </div>

  <button type="submit" (click)="getFormData(dataGroup.value)" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and in your **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;
 dataGroup: FormGroup;
 selectedGroups: string[];

  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService) {
   this.dataGroup = new FormGroup({
email: new FormControl(''),
password: new FormControl(''),
list: new FormControl('')
});
this.selectedGroups = [];
 }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

onCheckChange(event) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
 this.selectedGroups.push(event.target.value);
} else {
 const index = this.selectedGroups.findIndex(item => item === event.target.value);
 if (index !== -1) {
  this.selectedGroups.splice(index, 1);
}
}
}

   getFormData(value){
      value['groups'] = this.selectedGroups;
      console.log(value);
  }


}
```

Comment: The value of pre selected checkbox is showing 0 value in array until I check the checkbox maually,Can you please help me

Comment: Okay, so let's say you want group1 to be pre-selected, Then just initialize selectedGroups array with group1. this.selectedGroups = ['group1']. Try this and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with Angular, I would recommend you to use [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), which is natively available in Angular. As stated on the [introduction to reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#introduction-to-reactive-forms),

> Reactive forms use an explicit and immutable approach to managing the
>   state of a form at a given point in time. Each change to the form
>   state returns a new state, which maintains the integrity of the model
>   between changes. Reactive forms are built around observable streams,
>   where form inputs and values are provided as streams of input values,
>   which can be accessed synchronously.

To achieve that, you will need to import `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` onto your component's module.ts

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    // other imports
    ],
  // others
})
```

Then, on your component.html, you will need to bind your form to a `formGroup`, and supply each `input`/`select` with a `formControlName`

```
<form [formGroup]="newForm" (ngSubmit)="getFormData()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input formControlName="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input formControlName="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">List:</label>
    <select formControlName="list" class="form-control" multiple>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div formGroupName="groups" class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Group:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="group1">group1
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="group2">group2
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then, on your component.ts, you will need to initialise your `formGroup`, and handle the submit event, which will print out the values of your form.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  newForm = this.fb.group({
    email: [''],
    password: [''],
    list: ['one'],
    groups: this.fb.group({
      group1: [false],
      group2: [false],
    }),
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  getFormData() {
    const res = { ...this.newForm.value };
    res.groups = Object.entries(res.groups).map(item => {
      if (item[1]) {
        return item[0];
      };
    }).filter(n => n);
    console.log(res);
  }
}
```

I have created a short demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqugbf?file=src/app/app.component.html), but I believe you should read up more about [FormBuilders, FormGroups, and FormControls](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#generating-form-controls-with-formbuilder) on the official Angular tutorial to gain a better understanding of what you can do with Reactive Forms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually  select and checkbox value may contains multiple value so it should be an array like {"email":"test@mail.com","password":"test123","list":["one"],"groups":["group1","group2"]}

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER it was only a partial example of how to do it. I have updated to include the full solution on how to achieve your desired result. I have also updated the demo URL on my answer.